# Label is missing error eclipse

Tags: java, android

```
 float f1 = 4.0F;
  localPaint.setTextSize(f1);
  int j = howManyBreaks(str, localPaint, paramInt1);
  int i = 0;
  while (true)
  {
    if ((f1 >= f2) || (j > paramInt2))
      break label142;    //getting error here
    i = 1;
    f1 += 0.5F;
    if (f1 >= f2)
      break;
    localPaint.setTextSize(f1);
    j = howManyBreaks(str, localPaint, paramInt1);
  }
  f1 = f2;
  if (i != 0)
    label142: f1 = f1 - 0.5F - 0.5F;   // but i have placed label142 here
  paramTextView.setTextSize(0, f1);
```

In this above code I get error as: "label142 is missing"
Can anyone please rectify this error, if not possible please tell me an alternative for this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: actually it is not written by me. this coding is self generated from jd-gui tool. Can anyone please tell me a nice tool to convert from .class to java file?

Comment: That explains a few things ;-) Maybe you could try to improve readability on it a bit, e.g. by renaming variables; this should help you with trying to find out what the bit of code is actually trying to do. If you're just trying to get this to work and aren't worried about it being good code, my answer below should help you figure out that you just need to move the label outside the if-condition, which answers your original question. Your question about a conversion tool should probably be posted on http://superuser.com/ or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You really should be avoiding labels... google "goto considered harmful".

Your problem is that your label is in an if-block, so it's not available from where you're trying to call it.

Comment: So can you please tell me any alternative for this

Comment: One way to change this would be to put the code inside your while-block in a method instead and use that method's return value to determine whether to loop again.

Answer (score 1):

`label142` is inside the `IF` statement it should be before the `While` if you want it break the loop just use `break`

Also, `goto label` is not a good option in programming, it makes the complex and hard to read, let alone maintain, try to avoid it.

Comment: actually it is not written by me. this coding is self generated from jd-gui tool. Can anyone please tell me a nice tool to convert from .class to java file?

Comment: Cavaj Decompiler   http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.cnet.com%2FCavaj-Java-Decompiler%2F3000-2213_4-10071619.html&ei=NnUOT93lJ82n8gObvoDMAw&usg=AFQjCNGJTimYX_tlafuqamydNgLn4t8KHQ&sig2=ZSTqSixYm1YxtlROAdZbJg